# Is the expression "ne pas se faire prier" a euphemism, sarcasm, or litotes?

Tags: sens, usage

> Elle a son utilité, connaissant les hommes les plus influents de ce pays. Sans compter qu’elle **ne se fait pas prier** pour remplir nos obligations diplomatiques.

À part le fait qu’elle se porte volontaire pour remplir ces tâches qui ne lui reviennent pas, je me demande si cette expression laisse aussi entendre qu’elle se permet de se les approprier ?

Est-ce qu’on y associe forcément une connotation negative, soit son implication déplacée dans une affaire qui ne la regarde pas ? L’expression « ne pas se faire prier » relève-t-elle de l’euphémisme qu'on emploie pour éviter de dire grossièrement « y mettre son nez » ?

Comment: It's just writing. To not need to be asked to do something. Is that a euphemism, sarcasm or a litote in English?? Grammar and meaning is one thing and stylistic devices are others.

Answer (score 2):

Non, il n'y a pas nécessairement de connotation négative.

***Ne pas se faire prier*** indique simplement qu'une personne prend promptement elle-même l'initiative de faire quelque chose qui lui incombe sans que quelqu'un d'autre ne le lui ai suggéré, demandé ou imposé.

Comment: Je crois déceler quelque nuance entre « ne pas se faire prier pour ... » et « se porter volontaire pour ... », le premier se penchant vers un côté negative. Qu’est-ce que tu en penses ? D'un autre côté, je me demande s'il s'agit plutôt d'une litote qui sert à mettre en relief l’idée de « de gaieté de cœur » ou « avec entrain » ?

Comment: Oui, *ne pas se faire prier* et *se porter volontaire* sont très différents. Dans le premier cas, la personne est probablement la seule à qui la tâche incombe tandis que dans le deuxième, il existe un choix non préférentiel entre plusieurs exécutants potentiels.